# O que é volatine em C

Tags: c

Eu estou lendo essa apostila (http://www.inf.ufpr.br/lesoliveira/download/c-completo-total.pdf) e me deparei com o modificador `volatile`. Não entendi muito bem como funciona, então minha dúvida é:

- Para o que ele é usado?
- Onde posso usa-lo?
- Tem alguma relação com `const`?
- O que acontece se eu usar `const` e `volatine` juntos?

A apostila diz:

> Por exemplo, um endereço de uma varíavel global pode ser passado para
>   a rotina de relógio do sistema opercaional e usado para guardar o
>   tempo real do sistema. Nessa situação, o conteúdo da variável é
>   alterado sem nenhum comando de atribuição explícito no programa.

Logo em seguida:

> O modificador volatile previne a ocorrência dessas mudanças

Então quer dizer que se eu colocar volatile seria que não ocorrerá mais alterações naquele terminado dado?

Página: 42

Comment: Poderia informar por gentileza em qual página está escrito isto?

Comment: Vou fazer a alteração na pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado, vou fechar a pergunta.